# How do I take back a feature request?

Tags: support

I opened a feature request and got good replies - and now I don't think that the new feature is needed any more.

How can I make this clear? Is it possible to take back the feature request?

Comment: Why would you? If it's implemented, it must have been valuable enough. If not, then there's no problem anyway.

Comment: I don't think you've got anything to worry about on [that one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144929/can-we-get-a-new-question-type-for-forwarded-questions) :-). As @Bart says if it doesn't get implemented then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it was a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) you posted here in meta, you are certainly welcome to respond with another answer your own "question" (i.e. the feature request) to provide your recent epiphany and current view.

But once you post something to this public forum, it is really no longer yours to simply remove. Others have already contributed their ideas and thoughts to that thread. Even more users took the time to read through the content and vote appropriately. Reputation was awarded, etc, etc. It becomes part of the collective knowledge of this system for the benefit of *future* users. Even if the idea turns out to be misguided or no longer needed, that conversation is still useful to have around… or to have removed as the *community* decides.

Long story short, once a question is asked on Stack Exchange — whether it is for Q&A or meta — the life cycle and usefulness of that question goes well beyond the original person asking it.